# Excel Insert Formula into Cell Reference to Another Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

How can I insert a formula into cell reference to another sheet

For example,

General Formula

Cell D[x] = Analysis!I[x*9 + 5]

e.g.

Cell D1 =Analysis!I16 (Analysis Sheet Cell I 14)

Cell D2 =Analysis!I25 (Analysis Sheet Cell I 23)

Cell D3 =Analysis!I34 (Analysis Sheet Cell I 32)

How do I type it as a formula ?

[image: See image]

Comment: You just simply goto cell D4 press delete , type = and change the sheet to Analysis and select the cell you want.

Comment: Hi Imran, if I would like to do the same thing for the whole of column D, how do I do it without copy and pasting for each cell?

Comment: Just drag the formula.

Answer (score 0):

@WXYZ try to use: =INDIRECT("Analysis!" & ADDRESS(ROW()*9+5,9))

Comment: Hi Error 1004! Really appreciate your help but I needed to do more than that! As you can see I am only taking every 9th row from the Analysis sheet (Cell D[x] = Analysis!I[x*9 + 5] ), so I would like to create a formula so I can just copy and paste the formula until D[100] without having to alternate between sheets and clicking every single time

Comment: For now when I copy D1 formula to D2, I will get the value from I15 instead which is wrong because I actually need the value from I23 (every 9th row)

Comment: @WXYZ i edit my answer.i think the new answer fit your requirements!

Comment: Hi Error 1004! Where do you specify the column alphabet (letter I) in the formula though?

Comment: @WXYZ i dont specify the column with a letter instead i specify the column with number.(the last 9 before the 2 brackets)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are trying to do.. You want to have the value of each cells in column 'I' in the cells of the column 'D'. So you can simply do it graphically by typing '=' in cell D6 (for example) by fetching the value from the same worksheet or from another spreadsheet; by clicking again in the cell that you want to get its value.
For deploying (to Extend) and applying the formula to other cells you can take a look at : https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/867-excel-apply-formula-to-entire-column-row.html

It's very easy.

Comment: Hi Mohamad! Really appreciate your help but I needed to do more than that! As you can see I am only taking every 9th row from the Analysis sheet (Cell D[x] = Analysis!I[x*9 + 5] ), so I would like to create a formula so I can just copy and paste the formula until D[100] without having to alternate between sheets and clicking every single time

Comment: For now when I copy D1 formula to D2, I will get the value from I15 instead which is wrong because I actually need the value from I23 (every 9th row)